Firestore - can I query for one doc with parameter other than ID?
I'm coming from MongoDB and I'm struggling to understand getDoc() and getDocs().
Do I understand this correctly?
Does getDoc() only accept the document's ID as a parameter? Or can I do a query?
In the documentation I can only find code like this:
const docRef = doc(db, "collection", "11aa22bb33ccc");
const myDoc = await getDoc(docRef);

But what if I don't know the ID or I want to search with a different parameter, such as a field called author? Is it correct that I would not be able to do that with getDoc()?
With MongoDB, I can do db.collection.findOne({ author: "jones" }).
Can I not do that with Firestore?
So if I want to use a query, do I always need to use getDocs()?
If that is the case, I know that I can use limit(1) but handling the response to retrieve that one document feels not-as-smooth-as-mongodb.
I tried this:
const documents = collection(firebaseDb, 'documents');
const query = query(documents, where('author', '==', 'jones'));
const authorDocs = await getDocs(query, limit(1));
console.log(authorDocs[0].data());

And I got an error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')
So I think I have to use a forEach, like this:
authorDocs.forEach(doc => console.log( doc.data() ));

But, for only one document? That seems odd. Is there a better way?

Have a look at this Documentation.

hi @SandeepVokkareni thanks for replying, however, that's the same documentation I've been looking at. Where it says docRef = doc(db, "cities", "SF"), SF is the document ID, right?


Does getDoc() only accept the document's ID as a parameter?

No, getDoc() requires an argument of type document reference that points to a document that exists in a Firestore collection.

But what if I don't know the ID or I want to search with a different parameter, such as a field called author?

Then indeed you need to use a query that looks like this:
const queryByAuthor = query(collection(db, "documents"), where("author", "==", "jones"));


Is it correct that I would not be able to do that with getDoc()?

Yes, getDoc() is used to read a single document and not multiple documents that a query returns. If you want to read all documents then indeed you need to use getDocs() and loop over the results:
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(queryByAuthor);
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
  console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
});

If you only want to read the first document, then you should read the document at index 0, querySnapshot[0]:
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(queryByAuthor);
if (querySnapshot.docs.length > 0) {
  const doc = querySnapshot.docs[0];
  console.log('Document data:', doc.data());
}

Besides that, always be sure to not use undefined objects to create references or Firestore queries.

you said no to my question about getDoc() only accepting an ID. But in the documentation there is an example like this docRef = doc(db, "cities", "SF"). SF is the document ID, right?

I said no, in your context, where you're using a document reference. But indeed getDoc() can accept a document ID as an argument.

ok thanks for clarifying. Could I get a little more clarification please. And getDoc() can't accept a query as an argument, right? Only the document ID? You said it "can accept..." so I'm just double checking. Thanks.

Yes, getDoc() can not accept a query as an argument, only getDocs() can.

Alex, one more question. I noticed that you used .docs[0] and I tried that and it worked. How come we can run forEach() with querySnapshot but this doesn't work: querySnapshot[0]?

The forEach already exists in the first code snippet. You need to query the querySnapshot not the first document inside the result, right?

in one of your code examples, you used querySnapshot.forEach() and in another one of your code examples you used querySnapshot.docs[0]. I'm wondering, why does this not work: querySnapshot[0]?

That's because a querySnapshot object is iterable while querySnapshot[0] is not. Please keep in mind that querySnapshot[0] returns a Firestore document.
